# How do I strip subdirectories when using maven dependency plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

There is a jar file with following structure:

```
/--
  |-dir1
   |-file1
   |-file2
   |-file3
  |-dir2
  |-dir3
```

I set filter to take files only from dir1

```xml
<includes>dir1/*</includes>
```

it successfully takes files only from that directory, but in target directory copied files are placed in dir1, how can remove path from files that are copied and leave there only name. So `file1` will be copied to `target/file1` and not to `target/dir1/file1`

```xml
<build>
        <finalName>${project.build.finalName}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
                                    <version>version</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>target/natives</outputDirectory>
                                    <includes>dir1/*</includes>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: I can't understand this. Please post the pom config you are using.

Comment: @bmargulies, I use `maven-dependency-plugin`. I updated question with except from pom file.

Comment: Perhaps we can solve it in a different way. _Why_ do you want to do that?

Comment: @orien, I have a defined structure of a jar file which I have to conform to, that is why I want to change tree structure

Answer (score 11):

Support for the fileMappers tag was added in version 3.1.2 of the maven-dependency-plugin.

See official documentation [Rewriting target path and file name](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/unpacking-filemapper.html)

For example you could extract a nested .so file and place at a top level

```
<artifactItem>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.2</version>
    <includes>com/sun/jna/linux-x86/*.so</includes>
    <fileMappers>
        <fileMapper implementation="org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.filemappers.FlattenFileMapper"/>
    </fileMappers>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/extracted-libs/</outputDirectory>
</artifactItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to do what you want. If I had your problem, I'd use the antrun plugin to rearrange, or I'd build a different artifact to pull from.